# Android Progress not holding view when used with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I'm trying to implement a recyclerView showing the progress of some Activities, I decided to use android ProgressBar to represent the progress.
The problem is that the progressBar View does not hold the represented data when i set the progress in onBindViewHolder() or does even show at all sometimes.

I tried some suggestions, e.g. setting the visibility and "setIndeterminate()" in a separate AsyncTask, nothing works.

PS: I'm using a custom drawable, but it does work also with normal Horizontal ProgressBar.

Screenshot of the preview in Android Studio :

[image: Preview]

```java
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ObjectivesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Objective objective = objectives.get(position);
        holder.objectiveTextView.setText(objective.getObjectiveTitle());
        holder.goalTextView.setText(objective.getGoal() + "");
        holder.achievedTextView.setText(String.valueOf(objective.getAchieved()));
        new pbUiThread(holder.objectiveProgressBar).execute();
        holder.objectiveProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().mutate();
        holder.objectiveProgressBar.setProgress((int)objective.getProgress());
        if (objective.isDone()) holder.objectivesRow.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
        else holder.objectivesRow.setAlpha((float) 1.0);
    }
```

AsyncTask:

```java
public class pbUiThread extends AsyncTask<ProgressBar, Void, Void> {

        ProgressBar progressBar;
        public pbUiThread(ProgressBar progressBar) {
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ProgressBar... progressBars) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

ProgressBar in the XML Layout

```xml
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/objectiveProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/pb_circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

I used the same layout in another Fragment without RecyclerView and it works like it should.

Any Help ?

**Update:**
After hours of debugging i found that the problem was in my data modelI have set the progress field to be ignored by the DB using Room's @Ignore annotation since I thought i only need it for the UI)

```java
    @Ignore
    private float progress;
```

PS: I'm still kept a handler to update the progress

```java
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                holder.objectiveProgressBar.setProgress(progress);;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldnt save progress in your view especially in recycler view because it will be reused other information will be set to it and your information will be lost. instead try save it in any model that makes sense and set progress from that model in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: That's what I'm actually doing ? or can you clarify your answer more please ?